# Need a SQL Query for Getting matched and not matched Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My table structures are shown here:

**Table1**

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 20 |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 30 |
| 40 |

**Table2**

| Col1 |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 30 |
| 40 |

My expected result is this:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Matched |
| 20 | Matched |
| 20 | Not Matched |
| 20 | Not Matched |
| 30 | Matched |
| 30 | Not Matched |
| 40 | Matched |

Query I'm trying to use:

```
SELECT 
    T1.Col1,
    CASE
        WHEN T2.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Matched'
        ELSE 'NotMatched'
    END AS Col2
FROM
    Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 T2 ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1;
```

Comment: beside `Col1`, you will need to also left join on `row_number()`

Comment: Are you really using 2005 version? This version is out of extended support since April 2016. if you're using it, you really should upgrade.  (and I really can't remember but I think window functions was introduced to SQL Server in 2008 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can stick with your join approach, but use `ROW_NUMBER` to keep track of occurrences:

```sql
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) rn
    FROM Table2
)

SELECT T1.Col1,
       CASE WHEN T2.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Matched' ELSE 'NotMatched' END AS Col2
FROM cte1 T1
LEFT JOIN cte2 T2
    ON T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 AND T1.rn = T2.rn
ORDER BY T1.Col1, T2.Col1 DESC;
```

Comment: That will work, assuming the OP did get this tags wrong and he isn't working with 2005 version but with something a little more up-to-date. (btw, I personally would use `rank()` instead of `row_number()` for this but I don't think it matters so much)

Answer (score 0):

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1 (
        Col1 INT
    );
    
     
    INSERT INTO Table1 (Col1) VALUES
        (10),
        (20),
        (20),
        (20),
        (30),
        (30),
        (40);
    
     
    CREATE TABLE Table2 (
        Col1 INT
    );
    
     
    INSERT INTO Table2 (Col1) VALUES
        (10),
        (20),
        (30),
        (40);

    select T1.col1,case when T2.col1 is null then 'NotMatched'  else 'Matched' end col2
    from 
    (
    select col1 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.col1   ORDER BY t.col1   ) er
    from table1 t 
    ) as T1
    left join 
    (
    select t.col1 ,count(*) er2
    from table1 t 
    group by t.col1 
    ) as T2
    on T1.col1=T2.col1 and T1.er=T2.er2
    order by 1,2
    ;
```

[Run](https://dbfiddle.uk/b_6ZX8I4)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming table2 contains distinct values only, you can use `row_number()` to assign a unique number to each row then `left join` first record per partition only :

```
select t1.Col1, CASE WHEN t2.Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Matched' ELSE 'Not Matched' END AS Col2
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by Col1  order by Col1 ) as rn
  from table1
) as t1
left join table2 t2  ON t1.Col1  = t2.Col1 and rn = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kz2zjJGu)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution

```
select 
    a.col1 , 
    case when a.col1 = b.col1 then 'Matched'
         else 'Not Matched' end as col2
from
(
    select * , row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) as seq from tab1 
) as a left join (select col1 , row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col1) as seq from tab2) as b
on a.seq = b.seq and a.col1 = b.col1;
```